# Class type as parameter, and class forward

Tags: c++, oop

I create a simple game engine and I have little problem with switching scene.

I have 2 class: Game and Scene

In Game class, I have 2 pointers to scenes, and switchScene() method, which I want to share to Scene objects.

In Scene class I want to have a pointer to the game object, but this does not work.

Game.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include "Scene.cpp"

class Game{
    public:
        Game();
        ~Game();
        void init(const char* title, int width, int height, bool fullscreen, int fps);
        void switchScene(Scene* scene);
    private:
        Scene* stage = nullptr;
        Scene* tmpStage = nullptr;
};
```

Scene.hpp

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Game.hpp"
class Game;

class Scene{
    public:
        Scene(std::string sceneName);
        ~Scene();
        void setGame(Game* g);
    protected:
        Game* game;
};
```

In this way, I lost Game class definition, and get this error, when trying switch scene:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Game’
 game->switchScene(new Scene("A"));
```

What can I do with this? How can I put a reference to the game object to Scene?

Comment: Never include a `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you forward declare `Scene` in the `Game.hpp` header file, you can remove both the `#include "Scene.hpp"` (which it really should be) and the `#include "Game.hpp"` in the other header file

The remaining possible problem is that both source files needs to include both header files.